# Modifying the parameter of a looped function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with getting this JSFiddle to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/y45jN/

```
var mainFunction = function() {
  this.text;
}

mainFunction.prototype.start = function(printText) {

  this.text = printText;

  var func = function() {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += this.text + '<br/>';
  };

  setInterval(func,1000);

}

mainFunction.prototype.updateText = function(printText) {

  this.text = printText;

}

var test = new mainFunction();
test.start('hello');

setTimeout(function(){
  test.updateText('bye');
},5000);
```

What I want to do is for the first 5 seconds print hello and after 5 seconds print bye.

I'm unsure on how I can make the function (func) know that the this.text parameter of the class has changed.

Comment: use setTimeout with bind https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've messed up the context here. Cache `this` in some variable and use it inside an interval (or use `bind`):

```
    this.text = printText;
    var self = this;

    var func = function() {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += self.text + '<br/>';
    };
```

Then, simply modify the instance's property `text`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    test.text = 'bye';
},5000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y45jN/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this an entire evening till I gave up and came to stackoverflow!

Comment: One more question, how come the javascript bind works, but the underscorejs bind doesn't work "_.bind(func, {text:this.text})"

Comment: You are pushing completely different object as a context in this case. Simply use `_.bind(func, this)`

Comment: Jup that was it! You are all heroes!

Answer (score 0):

Solution using bind method:

```
setInterval(func.bind(this),1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y45jN/5/

Comment: Thank you, both solutions are great!

Comment: One more question, how come the javascript bind works, but the underscorejs bind doesn't work "_.bind(func, {text:this.text})"

Comment: it returns the function (it doesnt run it, just return the function itself) but inside the funtion, all "this" will point to the parameter used in bind. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind